# ImportXML query giving internal error

Tags: xml, xpath, web-scraping, google-docs

I have just wrote my first ImportXML function to fetch the products like this.
I want to fetch all `h3` elements. But its showing `import internal error`.

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/products?q=ipod+nano","//h3")
```

I tried this query also to give all the h3 elements with class `r`, but its still showing the same error?

```
=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/products?q=ipod+nano",
                "//h3[@clsass='r')")
```

Comment: Two ideas: a) Try a normal HTTP address first, since HTTPS often requires special handling or overriding options. b) The second XPath expression contains two errors. Try `//h3[@class='r']` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by @MarcusRickert already, HTTPS pages might be a problem. Use HTTP versions of them:

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&q=ipod+nano&gws_rd=ssl", "//h3")
```

The result is (clipped):

```
Apple iPod Nano (6th Generation) - 8 GB - Graphite
Apple iPod Nano (3rd Generation) - 4 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (4th Generation) - 8 GB - Pink
Apple iPod Nano (PRODUCT) RED (7th Generation) - 16 GB - Red
Apple iPod Nano (2nd Generation) - 4 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (5th Generation) - 8 GB - Black
Apple iPod Nano (4th Generation) - 8 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (7th Generation) - 16 GB - Space Gray
Apple iPod Nano (5th Generation) - 16 GB - Black
Apple iPod Nano (2nd Generation) - 4 GB - Green
.....
```

Do the same with your second query. Again, credit goes to Marcus for spotting two errors in your XPath expression. Try to be more careful with writing those expressions! Especially the `clsass` instead of `class` should be easy to catch if you look twice at your code.

```
=IMPORTXML("http://www.google.com/search?tbm=shop&q=ipod+nano&gws_rd=ssl", "//h3[@class='r']")
```

Result:

```
Apple iPod Nano (7th Generation) - 16 GB - Slate
Apple iPod Nano (6th Generation) - 8 GB - Graphite
Apple iPod Nano (3rd Generation) - 4 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (4th Generation) - 8 GB - Pink
Apple iPod Nano (PRODUCT) RED (7th Generation) - 16 GB - Red
Apple iPod Nano (2nd Generation) - 4 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (5th Generation) - 8 GB - Black
Apple iPod Nano (4th Generation) - 8 GB - Silver
Apple iPod Nano (7th Generation) - 16 GB - Space Gray
Apple iPod Nano (5th Generation) - 16 GB - Black
Apple iPod Nano (2nd Generation) - 4 GB - Green
Apple iPod Nano (3rd Generation) - 8 GB - Pink
Apple iPod Nano (PRODUCT) RED Special Edition (2nd Generation) - 4 ...
Apple iPod Nano (1st Generation) - 2 GB - White
Apple iPod nano (PRODUCT) RED Special Edition (6th Generation) - 8 ...
Apple iPod Nano (PRODUCT) RED Special Edition (3rd Generation) - 8 ...
Apple iPod Nano (PRODUCT) RED Special Edition (5th Generation) - 8 ...
Engraved Apple iPod Nano 16GB - 8th Gen
Apple 16GB iPod nano (Blue) Brand new
Apple iPod Nano (3rd Generation) - 8 GB - Green
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the credit! It's Mar*c*us by the way. The engine of SO is not so intelligent to correct that spelling. :-)

Comment: @MarcusRickert I see, apologies - The k spelling is just so much more common in Bonn!

Comment: Http part worked. Also i was giving the wrong URL so it was unable to parse.